# Using CakePHP's ORM, "Cannot redeclare class Foo"

Tags: php, database, cakephp, orm, model

Here is my database structure:

```
create table dpt_tutores
(
id int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
nivel varchar(128),
apellidos varchar(256),
nombres varchar(256),
email varchar(512),
estado varchar(128)
);


create table dpt_grupos
(
id int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
fecha_de_creacion datetime,
alumnos varchar(512),
titulo varchar(1024),
id_curso int,
informe_nota decimal(5,2),
informe_rango varchar(16),
predefensa_fecha datetime,
predefensa_gmt varchar(16),
predefensa_webex varchar(16),
defensa_fecha datetime,
defensa_gmt varchar(16),
defensa_webex varchar(16),
id_revisor int,
FOREIGN KEY (id_revisor) REFERENCES dpt_tutores(id),
id_guia int,
FOREIGN KEY (id_guia) REFERENCES dpt_tutores(id)
);

create table dpt_grupos_iteraciones
(
id int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
fecha datetime,
ubicacion_archivo varchar(512),
nota float(4,2),
id_grupo int,
FOREIGN KEY (id_grupo) REFERENCES dpt_grupos(id)
);
```

I've added the following Model (`dpt_grupo.php`):

```
<?php
class DptGrupo extends AppModel {

}
```

And my controller:

```
<?php
class DptController extends AppController {
  public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

  public function index() {
    $this->loadModel('Dpt_Grupo');
    $this->set('grupos', $this->dpt_grupo->find('all'));
  }
}
```

But when I run the action in that controller I get the error:

> Fatal Error Error: Cannot redeclare class DptGrupo     File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\foowebsite\app\Model\dpt_grupo.php     Line: 4
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create
>   app\View\Errors\fatal_error.ctp

How can I just find a list of all the rows in the `dpt_grupos` table?

Comment: While Cake can work just fine without following conventions, it requires more work on your part to make sure it's loading the right things. You may want to follow conventions and see if that works first. (Model names don't have underscores, are referenced by CamelCase, and their file names are CamelCased as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the model file to
DptGrupo.php

```
$this->loadModel('DptGrupo');
$this->set('grupos', $this->DptGrupo->find('all'));
```